# Input String not in correct format (Format Exception not handled)

Tags: c#, database, oledbdatareader

I am trying to parse the retried value from the database into `double`, `long`, or `integer`, but it throws a FormatException. I need your help.

In this code, I am trying to retrieve hours from the database and sum them to calculate total hours input into the database.

```
String hrs;
Double resultHrs=0;

while (oleDbDataReader1.Read())
{
    hrs = oleDbDataReader1["Hours"].ToString();
    double HRS = double.Parse(oleDbDataReader1["Hours"].ToString());
    resultHrs = resultHrs + HRS;
}// end while
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do the string conversion in the first place:

```
double hours = (double) oleDbDataReader1["Hours"];
```

Unless your value is *actually* a string in the database (in which case you should fix that) there's no reason to convert it *into* a string. (If it's not a type mapped to `double`, you should change what you cast it to, of course.)

EDIT: If it's non-numeric in the database, then you probably *do* need to use `double.Parse` - but you might want to specify the culture. For example, assuming they're all of the form "10.2" rather than "10,2" (as some cultures would use) you would want something like:

```
double hours = double.Parse((string) oleDbDataReader1["Hours"],
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @AbeerIslam: Why is it text at all, if it's always meant to hold a number?

Comment: I had to cast it anyway while inputting the value into the database that was my reason for doing that however i have changed it anyway

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
 HRS = oledbDataReader1.GetDouble(iColumn);
```

where iColumn is the column index in the query